# Docker sdk for python problem with execution

Tags: python, docker

I'm developing a python project that contains several classes that perform analysis but in a different way. some of these classes need to instantiate (at runtime) docker containers for the execution of some tasks. then via the command

```
client = docker.from_env()

container = client.containers.run('image-name', detach=True, ports={'8080/tcp': 8081})
```

doing the build with docker everything works, the problem arises with the execution then:

`docker run --rm -it my-image`

when i run this command i get the following error printed:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 600, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/app/v8_guide/__main__.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/v8_guide/__main__.py", line 62, in main
    core.execute_files()
  
  ...

  File "/app/v8_guide/files/engine_start.py", line 29, in run_analysis
    client = docker.from_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 96, in from_env
    return cls(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

to fix it I added the docker volume to the run command, like this:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ....`

however, I have read that this method is not optimal in terms of security (due to access to docker). Are there any better ways to get the application to work anyway without having these security related issues?